# How to break lines in dynamic content in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Have a dynamic content rendered from React JS that generates a follow HTML:

```
<a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

<a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

//...successively
```

I would like to render these links from 4 to 4 separated with line break `<br/>`
like this example bellow:

```
<a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

<a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

<a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

<a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

<br/> // <--- LINE BREAK

<a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

// ,,,successively
```

Here is a part of my component ReactJS code. Only the part of the code responsible for rendering is shown. The HTML renderization is working succefully.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.interiores.map(item =>
          <div>
            <div className="gallery">
              {
                item.fotos
                  .map(foto => {
                    return (<a href={`../images/${foto}.jpg`}
                      <img src={`../images/${foto}_thumb.jpg`} alt="" />
                    </a>
                    ) 
                  })
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
   }
```

How can I solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your end target is to give a break after every 4th `anchor` irrespective of a `br` tag, try this CSS rule:

```
a:nth-child(4n+4) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```css
a:nth-child(4n+4) {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

a {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: gray;
}/*This rule is only for visual representation*/
```

```html
<div>

  <a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

  <a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

  <a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

  <a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>


  <a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>
  <a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

  <a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

  <a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>

  <a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>


  <a href='../images/image_name.jpg.jpg'>
  <img src='../images/image_name_thumb.jpg' alt="" />
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
this.fotos.map(foto =>   .....
```

use

```
this.fotos.map((foto, index) =>   .....
```

to get the map iterator.

Then insert the following ternary operator after anchor tag:

```
.....
</a>
{index % 4 == 0 ? <br/> : <div></div>}
```

Which will conditionally insert br tag.

You can organize your code like this:

```
stackoverflow = () => {
  let fotos = [];
  let interiors = [];

  const gallery = (item) => item.fotos.map((foto, index) =>
    <div className="gallery">
      <a>
        <img>
        </img>
      </a>
      {index%4 == 0 ? <br/> : <div></div>}
    </div>
  )

  return(
    <div>interiors.map(item => gallery(item))</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Doing in this way here is a issue because you need to return only one parent tag who wrap the children tags it is mandatory on ReactJs. In this case it is retururned 2 sibblings tags: <a> and <br>. How to solve it?

Comment: What error you get? I think you can do it by wrapping with <div>. `<div> your stuff here </div>` @claudiobitar

Comment: It is mandatory  to have a parent tag on return: 
  .map(foto => {
                    return ( <div>...<-- parent tag 
Like for example: <div><a></a><br/></div> And this solution isn't useful for the goal.

Comment: The error message is: Unexpected token, expected , ( but this message doesn't have nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Looks like a syntax error. Looking in to it @claudiobitar

Comment: Here is the code:
return <a href={`../images/${foto}.jpg`} className="big">
                      <img src={`../images/${foto}_thumb.jpg`} alt="" />
                    </a>
                    { index % 4 == 0 ? <br/> : ''}                  
                    )

Comment: Updated the code, please try again. <br/> tag was wrong, ternary operator needs a false case and index for fotos.map not for interiors.map @claudiobitar

Comment: If you are using React 16.x.x you can use the Fragments API to solve that problem https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is

```
render() {
  let items = [];
  let images = [];
  this.state.interiores.map((item, i) => {
    item.fotos.map((foto, i1) => {
      images.push(<a key={i1} href={`../images/${foto}.jpg`}
        <img src={`../images/${foto}_thumb.jpg`} alt="" />
      </a>);
    });
    items.push(<div key={i} className="gallery">
      {images}
    </div>);
    items.push(<br />);
  });
  return (
    <div>{items}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The images quantity doesn't matter because it is a dynamic content and it must to be separated in groups with 4 <a> and 1 <br> after these. Like: <a>content</a><a>content</a><a>content</a><a>content</a><br/> and again... again...